# Javascript/CSS File Not Loading But is on the page! SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, master-page, css

I am able to see the the javascript files and css files in the code from the F12 Developer tools but the scripts/CSS files only load when i am logged in the Anonymous User it does not load. Is there anything i am doing wrong here is the code i am using at the moment.

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSRegistration1" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/jquery/themes/AFLLCMainTheme/jquery.ui.all.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSRegistration2" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Styles/AFLLCCustomTemplate.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSRegistration3" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Styles/AFLLCCustomTemplateMenu.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSRegistration4" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Styles/AFLLCCustomTemplateSearch.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CSSRegistration5" Name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Styles/AFLLCCustomTemplateSocialMedia.css %&#62;" After="corev15.css" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink7" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/jquery/js/jquery.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink8" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/jquery/js/jquery-ui.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink9" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/jquery/js/jquery.resize.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink10" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/AFLLCMenuScripts.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink14" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/AFLLCMenuWidget.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink11" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/SocialMediaWidget.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink12" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/SiteSettingsWidget.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink13" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="false" Localizable="false" Name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/AFLLCCustomTemplate/Scripts/AFLLCCustomTemplate.js" runat="server" language="javscript">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

Comment: Well...you commented everything out for starters.

Comment: Are all the files not loading or just the custom files? Make sure the files are checked in and the user has access to them.

Comment: they are not commented out that is how they look when creating master page from a html file. when copied to the server it automatically fills in the correct code. I did get an answer this was an execute problem. so when i moved the custom coded files to the site assets folder and retried it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the files to the SiteAssets folder allowed the files to run correctly.

Comment: Accept your own answer as answer to the question, so it will not show in unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is that simple:
did you check if your script/css-files in the library are checked in and published (main version?).

Anonymous user only see main/published versions, while you, as you have edit permissions, are allowed to see files in draft-mode too.